# Win7 Performance Monitor: Capture Error - fewer than 2 data samples

Tags: performance, windows-7, monitor

When I use Windows 7 Performance monitor tool, having defined a simple collector set (eg CPU), after capturing for a few minutes at 1 update per second, when opening the new  report blg I get: "Error occurred trying to complete this operation: At least one of the input  binary log files contain fewer than two data samples).

I've tried changing the setting under General: Run As   from USER to  mydomain\username   that I log into my laptop with, but still the same is returned as a result after capturing.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed either by editing the properties of the User Defined Data Collector Set so that, for example:

Run As = domain\user

and

security = Everyone with Full Permissions enabled.

...At least, to get around this problem initially.

Answer (score 0):

If suggestion to change "run As = domain\user" didn't work, it could be that you didn't wait enough to capture samples, if you use 1 minute interval try to run performance monitor using your Data Collector Set at least for 3-5 mins that captured samples could draw you a diagram.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you stop your Data Collector Set before the defined Sample time in Properties, Click on Properties of user defined Monitor and reduce Sample time to 1 minute and then check report after couple of minutes, this will isolate that its not due to Sampler Interval.

Answer (score 0):

Try other performance counters in Data Collector Properties window.

In my case `\Processor(_Total)\` gives the same error, but `\Processor Information(_Total)\` works.